# lvalue required as left operand of assignment c++ in Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort, lvalue

I see many different answers to this question and have looked at many of them yet I cannot find the answer to my problem.
I have this error

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I'm using bubble sort function to sort double value in my array of objects

```
void BubbleSort(Student* student=new Student[5])
{
    double temp;
    for(int i2=0; i2<=4; i2++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if(student[j].getBal() > student[j+1].getBal()) {
                temp = student[j].getBal();
                student[j] = student[j+1];
                student[j+1].getBal() = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my class

```
double getBal()
{
    return this->bal;
}
void setBal(double bal)
{
    this->bal=bal;
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `getBal()`

Comment: `Student* student=new Student[5]` as a default argument is pure evil. How do you know whether or not you should `delete` the parameter?

Comment: Your swapping logic is incorrect, suddenly you have two students that are the same, but with different balances.

Comment: instead of `student[j+1].getBal()=temp;` write `student[j+1].setBal(temp);`

Comment: `student[j+1].getBal()=temp;` here you are using `getBal` instead of `setBal`!!

Comment: `student[j+1].setBal(temp); ` This is the solution. Thank you !

Comment: You shouldn't need to mess with the "Bal" (whatever that is) separately. If your `Student` has a reasonable definition, `std::swap(student[j], student[j+1]);` is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a statement like `student[j+1].getBal()=temp;` to make sense, `getBal()` would have to return a *reference* to a member variable of the class. Your statement would then modify the value of that member variable *through* that reference.

But don't do it that way: the more normal thing to do would be to provide a `setBal()` method that takes a `double` as a parameter.

Comment: `student[j+1].setBal(temp);` This is the solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

student[j+1].getBal()=temp;

function call are "Rvalue". This mean that you can't assign them.
What you're doing is a bit like trying to write `1 = temp`.